# Finding a path whose elements sum up to a given number in a matrix

Tags: java, c++, algorithm

Given a `M x N` matrix and a positive integer `p`, how can I find a continuous path recursively through the matrix starting at position `0,0` that will sum to `p`? You can move left (col - 1), right (col + 1), up (row - 1) or down (row + 1), and can only use a position once in the path. If there is such path in the matrix, output it in a separate matrix with the same shape, by filling the positions on the path with 1 and the rest positions with 0.

I literally froze and could do anything, is there any technique for solving these kinds of problems? How would one go on about approaching this problem, a solution would be much appreciated.

Here is an example where `p = 73`:

```
2  8  15 
1  10 5
19 19 3  
5  6  6
2  8  2
```

Output:

```
1  0  0
1  0  0
1  1  1
1  1  1
1  1  1
```

Comment: Firstly your question is not clear, provide example input matrix & the output you want. secondly for the above task what code you wrote so far ?. Also please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: How much do you know about recursion, and using it to write a brute force algorithm that tries all possible paths? If you have absolutely no idea where to start, you might want to review what you've learned so far (or learn more stuff). Also, is this Java or C++? Please don't use irrelevant tags.

Comment: i provided the example, i couldnt write a solution i didnt know where to start, thats why i posted this question so that i can get help

Comment: Note that 2, 8, 15, 5, 10, 19, 6, 6, 2 is also a possible solution.

Comment: This problem is NP-complete.

Answer (score 1):

"Should randomly move" is (possibly intentionally) misleading.  What you want to do is effectively a depth-first search, systematically testing possible routes.  A route terminates if it equals (you're done) or exceeds the target number, in which case you back up.

If we assume the route can't double back on itself (you didn't say), then what would work is a left- (or right-) edge following pattern, like a standard maze solver.  So at each new node visited, it proceeds to the left-most non-visited adjacent node, subsequently trying other adjacent nodes in a clockwise direction.

(If the route *can* revisit nodes, then treat the matrix as a 4-tree and pick an arbitrary direction to test first.)