# Efficiently finding a path in a matrix whose elements sum to a target number?

Tags: algorithm, computer-science

**Programming Problem**

*Input:* m x n matrix of strictly positive numbers, target number T.

*Output:* a simple path starting at entry (0,0) and ending on the bottom row. We are only allowed to *move right or down* at any given step. Furthermore, the path elements MUST sum up to exactly T. There are no additional constraints.

I have implemented a correct brute-force solution, but we're talking about exponential time. Does a more efficient solution exist (perhaps using dynamic programming)?

I saw a similar existing question, but the answers are limited and someone claimed this problem to be NP-Complete, but I have been unable to verify this:
[Finding a path whose elements sum up to a given number in a matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50653255/finding-a-path-whose-elements-sum-up-to-a-given-number-in-a-matrix)

Comment: Are these paths allowed to reuse grid cells?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [mcve].

Comment: No, the path must be simple (just added this to my question, thank you for pointing this out).

Comment: I would suggest that an A* search might be in order here. The heuristic is the tricky part though. Is there a fixed start and end point the path must have? If there isn't, I think this may indeed be an NP-Complete problem.

Comment: What does "simple path" mean? Must it be a straight line?

Comment: A simple path does not reuse the same vertex (or in this case the same matrix entry/number) twice.


The start point must be the top-left entry, and the path must end on the bottom row (we can only move down or to the right).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Could you point me to a proof of NP-hardness (or related problem) so that I might solidify my grasp on why this might be?

Comment: There's another problem on the attached topic: there as you said you can move only down or right, but another problem doesn't have such limits. So it can be done in `O(mnp)` I guess with the dynamics, that stores whether you have path to each cell with such sum. Like `d` is 3-dimensional bool array and `d[n][m][p] = d[n-1][m][p-a[n][m]] or d[n][m-1][p-a[n][m]]`

Comment: Unrelated recommendation: Avoid tagging multiple languages unless the question is about interoperation between the languages or the question is about comparing the languages. For just about all other cases, pick the language you are most likely to use to implement the program. You could also use the `language-agnostic` tag to say you don't care which language is used, but few people monitor this tag, reducing the pool of eyes on the question.

Comment: "Does a more efficient solution exist" No. It is a very obviously an NP-complete problem. Subset sum easily reduces to it. Take a set of numbers. Create a matrix of 2×2N, put zeroes in the left column, put alternating zeroes and numbers from the set in the right column. If you can find a path that sums to T, you can find a subset that sums to T.

Comment: how is this question different from the one you linked? For clarification of answers, maybe better comment on the answers.

Comment: @CharlesDupont Firstly please update you question that you can go only to the right and down. This is VERY important. Secondly if we are talking about some efficiency please provide us with some constraints on `n`, `m` and `T`.

Comment: Done. There are no additional constraints on n, m and T.

Comment: So negative numbers are allowed?

Comment: Is there any structure to the numbers in the matrix? In that case, it may be possible to reduce the running time by a lot.

Comment: If you can only move down or right you need an NxN matrix and place the numbers from the set on the diagonal. This is still a polynomial reduction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can move only down or right as you said here [Efficiently finding a path in a matrix whose elements sum to a target number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56673063/efficiently-finding-a-path-in-a-matrix-whose-elements-sum-to-a-target-number#comment99913645_56673063), there is a solution which works in `O(nmT)`:

```cpp
// let a be given matrix
// d is 3-dimensional matrix: d[X-position][Y-position][sum]
vector<vector<vector<bool>>> d(n, vector<vector<bool>(m, vector<bool>(T + 1, false)));

// initialize dynamics
if (a[0][0] < T) {
    d[0][0][a[0][0]] = true;
}

// calcualte dynamics
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
        if (i == 0 && j == 0) {  // already calculated
            continue;
        }
        for (int k = 0; k <= T; k++) {
            bool isPossible = false;
            int prevSum = k - a[i][j];
            if (i > 0 && prevSum >= 0)
                isPossible |= d[i - 1][j][prevSum];  // step down
            if (j > 0 && prevSum >= 0)
                isPossible |= d[i][j - 1][prevSum];  // step right
            d[i][j][k] = isPossible;
    }
```

If one of the `d[n][i][T]` for each `i` is `true` (iterating over bottom row), then path exists, otherwise not.

Restoring path is not so hard too, just go up if `d[i - 1][j][sum - a[i][j]]` is true (or `i` is `0`), otherwise left.

UPD. This approach won't work with negative numbers.

UPD2. It would be great if someone tells how to initialize n-dimensional vectors with known size not such weird.